# Mapping C Union to C# struct

Tags: c#, c, interop, pinvoke

I am trying to map a C struct to C# to work with it in a wrapper class but keep running into a TypeLoadException on the struct because it:

> contains an object field at offset 2 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.

Here is the relevant C code:

```
#pragma pack(2)

tyedef unsigned char SPECIAL_ID[16];

typedef struct _idType
{
  unsigned char f;
  unsigned char t;
  union
  {
    unsigned short i_legacy;
    SPECIAL_ID i;
  }
} IDTYPE;
```

And here's the latest attempt at the C# struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack=2)]
public struct IDTYPE
{
  [FieldOffset(0)]
  public System.Byte f;
  [FieldOffset(1)]
  public System.Byte t;
  [FieldOffset(2)]
  public ushort i_legacy;
  [FieldOffset(2)]
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=16)]
  public StringBuilder i;
};
```

I have tried with and without the Pack=2. I've tried moving the union out to a separate struct with explicit layout and field offsets of 0 and then using that struct in a layout sequential struct for IDTYPE. I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always best to use a type for the union, and then aggregate it with the containing struct. That lets the framework lay out the types and calculate offsets, apart from the union where you place all members at offset zero.

The byte array in the union makes things more complicated. One option here is to use a fixed buffer.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public unsafe struct IDTYPE_UNION
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public ushort i_legacy;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public fixed byte i[16];
};
```

Put it in the containing struct like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=2)]
public struct IDTYPE
{
    public byte f;
    public byte t;
    public IDTYPE_UNION union;
};
```

Another option is to simply omit the `i_legacy` member and if you really do need to read out that data, do so from the byte array:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=2)]
public struct IDTYPE
{
    public byte f;
    public byte t;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=16)]
    public byte[] i;

    ushort i_legacy
    {
        get
        {
            return (ushort)((ushort)i[0] << 8 | (ushort)i[1]);
        }
    }
};
```

This option does allow you to avoid having to use unsafe code.

Comment: I really like the 2nd option to avoid unsafe but I'm having trouble setting the equivalent of i_legacy. In other words, I have a 2 byte array (the i_legacy size) which I set i equal to but I get an Argument exception because the marshalling of the array does not match the size of the struct. How would i set the equivalent of "i_legacy" in option #2?

Comment: Just add a setter to the property that assigns to indices 0 and 1 of the larger array.